# Nesting Callbacks Within Themselves

Tags: javascript, callback

I think I am looking for a nested callback but I'm really unsure about the terminology or programming methodology to use.

My problem I came across was when I was programming a way to get all results for a specific search with Google Places API.

There's no way for me to know how many results I'll have, so I'll need to loop through a callback if a certain object property exists with the response I get back from Google.

As far as I can tell, I need to check if another page exists, and if so, run the callback again but I'm unsure where to put that call at.  **It's definitely synchronous** as I have to wait for a response to determine whether to run again.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function secondCallback(error, response, body) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
}

function callback(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        var page_token = results.next_page_token;

        if (page_token) {
            console.log(results);
            console.log('there is another token to run');
            options.url += '&pagetoken='+page_token;
            console.log('with this token:' + options.url);
            request(options, callback); // doesn't work
            callback(); // doesn't work
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            console.log('no more results');
        }
    }
}

request(options, callback);
```

What's the most terse way to do something like this, assuming I could have a near-infinite number of iterations?

My console looks like this:

```
...
{ geometry: [Object],
   icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/generic_business-71.png',
   opening_hours: [Object],
   photos: [Object],
   scope: 'GOOGLE',
   types: [Object],
  status: 'OK' }
there is another token to run
with this token:https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=API_KEY&location=39.0997265,-94.57856670000001&radius=16093.4&keyword=guitar&pagetoken=CoQC9AAAAD8nKIOlABe_PU7NIaHP8320A7oY1avuGKYlpPMhba6HYwQmAhLvaGXPcPOlWK-V4VafGJLTUAmhplf7bvHv__fHSWSkkwvVpBzljntB9hMQIxoUnwZAyi3jU5Cyw2WQ_fZ3AJzLMO9ti_uv_Z2RAnAW694EDMDlyrONRKY3Yjrx0Ri9dJrzP0PWY2AtVJFqsLSquPb8azSnS3gINuCLe-Y5-Q18vq__V6pEuUNSipf_Trww1cGH67Q6oZ0aa6CAmrp8YSOJ7St6O1tmbj_N0gjBuNpqZ-k_YAhL3zeVYNIX8IWC3KHkVZkFAXSlN0RaV0Yd_K0gHpKeJmGLVjH5zlgSEAMR_J112AV2lAC7afssRPYaFFvW3fiySrpMQCsIsGpFSyWvulxm
{ html_attributions: [], results: [], status: 'INVALID_REQUEST' }
no more results
```

A quick search on Google Places API indicates this response for status: `INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that a required query parameter (location or radius) is missing.` However I'm verifying that I'm just sending the request url with `&pagetoken=PAGE_TOKEN` amended to it.

I've isolated it to these lines (see first code paste):

```
request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key='+apiKey+'&location='+latLong+'&radius='+radius+'&pagetoken=CoQC9AAAALHMvGfCqSR3TvplrBKu6Ra7YQXS1TpteDN0Cd_9HuyGUa1v7lFbFdCkezzqtG02CKBAkYpp1_VgOtz6Eu6ivKtsEsKNiHGj2KBvdI7tTZVxz-LZES8nZmcu-dFlDSKYYKVhD00sD26zAASvTGfdZ31wX62DesBxeI6TyPP3Zh6I_IW3W2yvUNZJ0hUNyZX-6t03YEDwacUw7oUL_gueOlkIIB93C4X0-zRyBFjzFUmAtzu45MXjINQ9RwHwlZnLqBqeKEhuWaTXBpxfkE1dQuuH4fIqBI-Ytnj_dDq4J1xhNav1Qk0BYo59PPqFVquWRI_KrJzm5fo11n4SeqAj_-4SEGMXaSFnDegQ5zWI-7qip4waFBj6NGnjVeXIjxTo3KpN4EdmigEa', secondCallback); // works
        console.log(pageToken); // is what it should be
        request('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key='+apiKey+'&location='+latLong+'&radius='+radius+'&pagetoken='+pageToken, secondCallback); // seems to be a proper string
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that waiting for a response cannot be done synchronusly, so you must make your function asynchronous.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, could you give me a short example?  I'm not dense enough to fill in the gaps with "think recursive" and adjusting my function to be asynchronous.  (Links or pseudocode will work well too)

Comment: I think that asynchronous `request(options, callback);` in your if-branch should actually work. Only I'm a bit unsure whether reusing the `options` object can work. Can you maybe post the logs you get in the console?

Comment: Sure thing, I've amended my question to reflect what `request(options, callback)` does.

Comment: Does this help (jQuery example)? http://jsbin.com/cecafiqexo/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Um, after `there is another token to run` I would expect a line along `with this token:`, where has it gone? You should use the network panel of your developer tools to check what requests are actually sent.

Comment: @istos yes, it does, I even copied in your jsfiddle JSON url and it worked well with a second callback to log out that JSON response to the console, however with my amended URL it doesn't.

Comment: @Bergi my bad, I cut it out, I'll add it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example that uses jQuery where on every Ajax success we make another Ajax call if our data has a `next_page_url` property.

```
function out(str) {
  $(document.createElement('h2'))
    .text(str)
    .appendTo(document.body);
}

function error(err, errText) {
  console.log('ERROR: ', errText);
}

function success(data) {
  if (data) {
    if(data.next_page_url) {
      // Make another request if our data has another URL
      request(data.next_page_url);
    }

    out(data.title);
  }
}

function request(url) {
  return $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(success)
  .fail(error);
}

request('http://jsbin.com/fohozupaqi/1.json');
```

The URLs we're requesting are:

- http://jsbin.com/fohozupaqi/1.json
- http://jsbin.com/wakihusaxu/1.json
- http://jsbin.com/qonijocexu/1.json

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/cecafiqexo/1/edit?html,js,output

I hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, very interesting, now I've isolated my problem to the request url.  if I input a string for my page token, I've got a good response, if I apply the variable I set earlier (pageToken) then it's no dice...  Even though pageToken and the whole url concatenated are the same thing...

Comment: Could it be that the request URL becomes invalid when you concatenate it with your variable? Invalid here I mean "totally an invalid URL per Browser spec" or "invalid per Google's API". Perhaps try logging it out.

Comment: Possible, but I'm unsure of other ways to get it in a string.  It's definitely sending the whole string as it should, I've string `String(pageToken)` but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: The last thing I would try would be to delay the requests with a `setTimeout`. Who knows, maybe Google doesn't like you making fast requests. Just a guess. Other than that I would just read their Docs for clues.

Comment: I'm not sure that would fix anything since pasting the entire URL as a string  will run it consecutively. edit: can confirm it doesn't.

Comment: You're correct!  I initially tried a 1000ms delay.  Then I saw how someone had a similar issue with iOS and someone suggested a timeout as you did.  when I set it to 5000 ms I didn't have a problem getting more.